# What is Perl's canonical way to calculate with 32 bit overflows?

Tags: perl

I try to convert the following C function to Perl:

```
uint32_t xorshift32 (uint32_t x32)
{
  x32 ^= x32 << 13;
  x32 ^= x32 >> 17;
  x32 ^= x32 << 5;
  return x32;
}
```

I came up with the following:

```
sub xorshift32
{
  my $r = '';
  vec ($r, 0, 32) = int($_[0]);

  vec ($r, 0, 32) ^= vec ($r, 0, 32) << 13;
  vec ($r, 0, 32) ^= vec ($r, 0, 32) >> 17;
  vec ($r, 0, 32) ^= vec ($r, 0, 32) << 5;

  return vec ($r, 0, 32);
}
```

Is this the canonical way to force 32 bit overflows in Perl or is there a better and faster way to do it?

I am also not sure if the code is correct. Will the result of the shift operations be a float on 32 bit systems?

Comment: @simbabque thanks corrected the typo

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs with expected outputs?

Answer (score 1):

I don't always know my canon, but I like the `0xFFFF_FFFF` bitmask for cases like this.

```
sub xorshift32 {
    my $x32 = shift;
    $x32  ^= $x32  << 13;
    $x32  ^= (($x32  & 0xFFFF_FFFF) >> 17);
    0xFFFF_FFFF & ($x32  ^ ($x32  << 5));
}
```

(haven't benchmarked this, don't know how it compares to `vec`)

And to answer your second question, no, the result of a `<<` bit shift operation will never be a float whether it is a 32-bit or 64-bit system, even if either operand is a float.

Comment: What is the result on a 32 bit system, if one shifts a 32 bit number to the left?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `& 0xFFFF_FFFF` where needed.

```
sub xorshift32 {
   my ($x32) = @_;
   $x32 ^= ($x32 << 13) & 0xFFFF_FFFF;
   $x32 ^= $x32 >> 17;
   $x32 ^= ($x32 << 5) & 0xFFFF_FFFF;
   return $x32;
}
```